# How to filter articles within a attr href with each and find usage ? simple tag list

Tags: jquery, filter, href, each, attr

I have got lots of div.articles and in that articles; i've got list of tags. I am trying hide article divs which don't got href = '#myFilter'.

I have no problem with reaching to href, my problem is reaching it's parent() without creating jQuery conflict .

[**Here is jsFiddle example to inspect.**](http://jsfiddle.net/nUsWT/25/)

jQuery

```
//trying to hide which don't got a href '#/news'
var news = '#/news';
$('.article a').each(function() {
    var category = $(this).attr('href');

    if ( category === news ) {//select only articles got #/news href in it
      //$(this).parent().parent().parent().show();//trying to reach article
        $(this).show();
    }else{
      //$(this).parent().parent().parent().hide();//this way hides all articles
        $(this).hide();//this works only on a elements
    }
});​
```

html:

```
<div class="article">
    <img src="http://content.photojo.com/content1.jpg" width="50" height="50" />
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#/news">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/nature">Nature</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/sport">Sport</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/hobbies">Hobbies</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="article">
    <img src="https://encrypt.google.com/content2.jpg" width="50" height="50" />
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#/nature">Nature</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/economy">Economy</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/world">World</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/hobbies">Hobbies</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each of the articles use a closure to track if you should hide the current item.
This won't have the flicker of nbrooks' answer.

As this fiddle shows: http://jsfiddle.net/878zQ/14/

```
var news = '#/news';
var nature = '#/nature';
var sport = '#/sport';
var hobbies = '#/hobbies';
var economy = '#/economy';
var world = '#/world';


$('.article').each(function() {

    var hide = 1;

    $(this).find('a').each(function() {

        var category = $(this).attr('href');

        if (category == news) { 
            hide = 0;
        }
    });


    if (hide == 1) $(this).hide();

});
```

To explain what this does, here is an english description of the functionality:

```html
For each page element containing a class of article.

    Set the hide flag to true

    For each a element in this page element

        Look at the href attribute and see if it matches the variable news
        If it does set the hide variable to false.

    If the hide flag is true hide this element.
```

Comment: really good answer mate, but still dont understand its logic. can you explain please?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**: New demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9GErB/
This eliminates the flash you were seeing before and also demonstrates how you can change the selector to use a variable. Relies on the [jQuery filter method](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), which is really what your question requires.

```
var news = '#/news';
var nature = '#/nature';
var sport = '#/sport';
var hobbies = '#/hobbies';
var economy = '#/economy';
var world = '#/world';

$('.article').filter(function() {
    return $(this).find('a[href="'+news+'"]').length==0;
}).hide();
```

This reduces the set of articles to those matching the filter expression, then hides them. This is much more efficient than iterating over articles and then iterating over links within each article.

---

Update: Working demo http://jsfiddle.net/WfdXE/

Use jQuery's `.closest()` method to get the nearest ancestor in the dom tree matching a certain selector.

```
$('.article').hide();
$('.article').find('a[href="#/news"]').each(function() {
    $(this).closest('.article').show();
});
```

​
The [jQuery attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) is `[name="value"]`.

To use a string variable here you can just do this:

```
var sel = "myFilter"; 
.find('a[href="'+sel+'"]') // this simply includes the text value of sel as the value
```

In JS you use `+` for string concatenation.

Comment: @barlas That's because the article contains other links which aren't '#/news' as well. You want to show the article as long as _at least_ one of the links is 'news'?

Comment: i know the conflict here, but need a resolution. i want to show articles only got '#/news' href, others must hide..

Comment: can i give a variation here? .find('a[href="#/news"]') --> like 'a[href="'news'"]'

Comment: @barlas you can put anything (legal characters or escaped with "\\" double backslash) in the double quotes and it will match that against the href.

Comment: @barlas oh ok no problem, I expanded my answer anyway

Comment: @barlas Sorry, I thought you said you understood how to change the variable name. I updated with a much simpler form of the code, which also eliminates the flashing effect (though that shouldn't have been a problem in an actual browser)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nUsWT/29/)**

```
$('.article').each(function() {
    $(this).find('a').each(function(){        
  if ( $(this).attr('href') === news ) {
    $(this).closest('.article').show();    
    return false;
  }else
      $(this).closest('.article').hide();            
  });
});​
```