# jquery find nearest class and remove it

Tags: jquery

I am trying to remove `list_product` entire block if that particular `delete` class is clicked. I am very new to jquery and still learning.

```
<div class='list_product'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='delete'>x</div>
        <div class='title'>Standing Fan</div>
     </div>
</div>
<div class='list_product'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='delete'>x</div>
        <div class='title'>Standing Fan 2</div>
     </div>
</div>
<div class='list_product'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='delete'>x</div>
        <div class='title'>Standing Fan 3</div>
     </div>
</div>
<div class='list_product'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='delete'>x</div>
        <div class='title'>Standing Fan 4</div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$('.delete').click(function() {
   $(this).find('.list_product').remove();
});
```

Is not working. may i know why and how do i fix it? thanks

Comment: this question may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11376207/how-to-filter-articles-within-a-attr-href-with-each-and-find-usage-tag-list

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just do `$(this).closest('.list_product').remove()`.
API ref: http://api.jquery.com/closest/
`find` searches through the children of the current element. In this case, the `.delete` elements don't have any children. Conversely, `closest` goes *up* thru the DOM, looking for the first ancestor with the class `list_product`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).closest('.list_product').remove();
   return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [event delegation](http://fooberry.com/2009/01/03/jquery-and-event-delegation/) on the parent element or use [Closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method

Closest is pretty easy to use :

```
var id = $("button").closest("div").attr("id");
```